# Derived UserControl not notified on parents changed DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inheritance, dependency-properties

I created a base `ClassA` which contains a `DependencyProperty` `MyText`. I derived a `ClassB` from that. This `ClassB` is embedded in a `MyCustomButton`. On MouseHover / MousePressed I change the MyText-Value of the embedded ClassB. But, while the parent ClassA fires an PropertyChanged-Event, the derived ClassB never changes the Property.

What would be the right way to notify the derived ClassB of the changing DependencyProperty? I already tried the solution mentioned at "[Base class DependencyProperty value change in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19560514/1147455)", but could not get this to work either.

My code:

The main window just consists of one MyCustomButton containing a ClassB-Instance:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cc:ClassB x:Key="MyClassB" MyText="MyClassBText"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <cc:MyCustomButton MyClassA="{StaticResource MyClassB}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MyCustomButton holds an instance of ClassA (actually, an instance of the derived ClassB):

```
class MyCustomButton : Button
{
    public ClassA MyClassA
    {
        get { return (ClassA)GetValue(MyClassAProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyClassAProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyClassAProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyClassA", typeof(ClassA), typeof(MyCustomButton));
}

<Style TargetType="{x:Type cc:MyCustomButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type cc:MyCustomButton}">

                <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
                        <cc:ClassA x:Name="ButtonClassA" Content="{Binding MyClassA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonClassA" Property="MyText" Value="HOVER"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="ButtonClassA" Property="MyText" Value="PRESSED"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

            </ControlTemplate>

        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

ClassA owns the DependencyProperty:

```
public class ClassA : UserControl
{
    public string MyText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyTextProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(ClassA), new PropertyMetadata("ClassA Default Text", MyTextPropertyChanged));

    private static void MyTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ClassA.MyTextPropertyChanged: " + e.NewValue);
    }

    public ClassA()
    {
    }
}
```

ClassB is derived from ClassA

```
static ClassB()
{
    MyTextProperty.AddOwner(typeof(ClassB), new PropertyMetadata(MyTextPropertyChanged));
}

private static void MyTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ClassB.MyTextPropertyChanged: " + e.NewValue); // This is just reached once at startup!
}

public ClassB()
{
    InitializeComponent();            
}

<local:ClassA 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CustomControlPlayground.CustomControls"
         x:Class="CustomControlPlayground.CustomControls.ClassB"
         x:Name="ClassBXAML">

    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, ElementName=ClassBXAML}"/>
    </Grid>
</local:ClassA>
```

**Update:**

All the answers I got so far seem to be right, but do not help with my issue. I think the problem might be in the way I bind the derived class. Could it be that like this my ClassB `MyClassB` is always casted to a `ClassA`?

In my MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <cc:ClassB x:Key="MyClassB" MyText="MyClassBText"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <cc:MyCustomButton MyClassA="{StaticResource MyClassB}" Width="100" Height="100"/>
</Grid>
```

In the MyButton-Style:

```
<StackPanel Background="Transparent">
    <cc:ClassA x:Name="ButtonClassA" Content="{Binding MyClassA, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: .Net-Style solution: In the PropertyChanged handler of classA, you can call an abstract method of base classA like "ForwardPropertyChange(..)", which is implemented in the derived classB.

Comment: Here's is just another hint: You can bind to nested properties in xaml using "+" e.g. in your case the syntax would be TextBlock Text="{Binding MyCustomButton+ClassA.MyText}". This is rare usage and the visual studio 2010 complains about it, but the compiler does not :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I saw is that, if not specified other, a *Dependency Property* is set to `BindsTwoWayByDefault=false`. Therefore you have only a binding from the source to the target. To enable a *Dependency Property* the allow binding from target to source you have to declare this at *Dependency Property* creation time:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextPropertyChanged =
    DependencyProperty.Register
    (
            "MyTextProperty",
            typeof(ClassA), 
            typeof(string),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata
            (
                    default(string), 
                    //the next line enables the binding back to source:
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault,
                    MyTextPropertyChanged
            )
    );

public static void MyTextPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
{
    //handling changed event
}
```

After inspecting your sample Project a saw that you are missing the `style` for `ClassA` and/or `ClassB`. Just remove the `XAML` for your ClassB, and just use the C# code and add following lines in `App.xaml` then all shall work:

```
<Application.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type customControls:ClassA}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type customControls:ClassA}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyText, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Remove the `XAML`-file from your ClassB, and just use the C# code.

Last I suggest you to write in ClassA respective ClassB following:

```
static ClassA()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ClassA), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ClassA)));
}

//and in ClassB

static ClassA()
{
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ClassA), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ClassA)));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems like FrameworkPropertyMetadata does not allow 3 Arguments in that way, I had to add some more: `public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(ClassA), typeof(string), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("ClassA DefaultText", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, MyTextFrameworkPropertyChanged, MyTextPropertyCoearceValueCallback, false, UpdateSourceTrigger.Default));`, but that causes the application to crash. Also, setting die binding to `Mode=TwoWay` didn't do the trick either

Comment: That [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms557296(v=vs.110).aspx) I provided shall work.
What is the error message at the time when the application crashes?

Comment: You are right. The error occured earlier. The property is named `MyTextPropertyChanged`, which caused trouble and `typeof(ClassA)` and `typeof(string)` were switched. This here compiles: `public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(ClassA), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("ClassA Default Text", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, MyTextPropertyChanged));`

Comment: But that still does not do it... :-/

Comment: Can you try removing the `Add Owner` in `B`. That is generally done if you want to add a `DP` from another control that is not present in the current inheritance hierarchy. i.e if you want to use the `TextProperty` from `TextBoxBase`

Comment: Plus add DefaultStyleKeyProperty to your static `ctor` in `B`

`DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(B), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(B)));`

Comment: Thanks again... but it still does not work that way.

Comment: Try the same as described above for the `MyClassAProperty`. The initial value is `null`. And after binding, the value is still null in code behind.

Comment: Do you have `binding errors` in the output view? Can you provide a sample Project?

Comment: No, no binding errors in the output. The code in the question does contain everything from my sample project.

Comment: But if you provide me a short sample project to show the error I can look at the issue.

Comment: Regarding your comment: there should already be a style in App.XAML (see my initial question).

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is not updating the `MyText` property of a `ClassB` instance; it is updating a `ClassA` instance.  Look at your template:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type l:MyCustomButton}">
  <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">
      <l:ClassA x:Name="ButtonClassA"
                Content="{Binding MyClassA,
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Border>

  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
              Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="ButtonClassA"
              Property="MyText"
              Value="HOVER" />
    </Trigger>
    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
              Value="true">
      <Setter TargetName="ButtonClassA"
              Property="MyText"
              Value="PRESSED" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Your triggers update the `MyText` property of `ButtonClassA`, which is a `ClassA` instance.  Your `ClassB` instance is the *`Content`* of `ButtonClassA`, but you never change its properties.  Since you never change `MyText` on a `ClassB` instance, the change handler is only invoked once: when the `MyClassB` resource is instantiated.

Note that you really **should not use a `UIElement` as a shared resource** because a `UIElement` can only be loaded into a single visual tree; it cannot have two owners.  To see the problem in action, add a second, identical `ClassA` instance to your `StackPanel` with the same `MyClassB` content.

---

As a nitpick, you should use `OverrideMetadata` instead of `AddOwner` when you add your callback in `ClassB`.  Use `OverrideMetadata` when you want to override the metadata of a property declared by an ancestor class.  Use `AddOwner` when you want to re-use a property declared by a class *outside of your base class hierarchy*.  For example, `Panel` and `Control` are in separate hierarchies, but they share the same `Background` property because `Control` re-uses the property declared by `Panel`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty BackgroundProperty =
        Panel.BackgroundProperty.AddOwner(
            typeof(Control),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                Panel.BackgroundProperty.DefaultMetadata.DefaultValue,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.None));
```

You don't need to use `AddOwner` because you're not attaching the property to a new class; you already inherit the property from your base class, so you only need to use `OverrideMetadata`.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for your answer! I tried to use `OverrideMetadata` like you and Grx70 recommended, but that also did not do what I hoped it would. I think, as you mentioned, there is something fundamental wrong the way I try to bind an instance of a class thats inherited of ClassA. Could you maybe point me in the right direction how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this should do the trick:

```
static ClassB()
{
    MyTextProperty.OverrideMetadata(
        typeof(ClassB),
        new PropertyMetadata("ClassB Default Text", MyTextPropertyChanged));
}
```

Here you override the `MyTextProperty`'s metadata for type `ClassB` with new metadata specifying `ClassB.MyTextPropertyChanged` as the property changed handler. Just make sure that in both cases (`ClassA` and `ClassB`) the type of metadata is the same, whether it's `PropertyMetadata`, `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` or any other type.

Note that this solution will stop `ClassA.MyTextPropertyChanged` from being called whenever you use instance of `ClassB`. If you want to add new handler instead of overriding the old one, you can do it like so:

```
public ClassB()
{
    DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(MyTextProperty, typeof(ClassB))
        .AddValueChanged(this, MyHandler);
}

private void MyHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //your handler code
}
```

Comment: This also does just call `MyTextPropetyChanged` only once at the instanciation of the class and never again. Might the way I bind it to the button be wrong?

Comment: Could be. One more thing that comes to my mind is that perhaps you're assigning the value of `MyText` property somewhere in code? If so, the setter uses `SetValue` method which actually replaces/dismisses current binding. To set the value maintaining the binding you should use `SetCurrentValue` method. Maybe that's the culprit. Could you submit the `e.OldValue` and `e.NewValue` values from the single invocation?